# how to read and insert a fixed field file into a database using pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to read a flat file with fixed fields and insert it into a table. I found this code that allows me to split the record into columns and assign it a header, but the created data frame has only 1 field of type string and when I insert the information into the table inserts everything into one column.

```
df = sqlContext.read.text("wasbs://container@almacen.blob.core.windows.net/TEXTPSD.DAT")
df.select(
    df.value.substr(1,12).alias('valor0'),
    df.value.substr(13,9).alias('valor1'),
    df.value.substr(22,12).alias('valor2'),
    df.value.substr(34,80).alias('nombre')
).show()
df1 = DataFrameWriter(df)
df1.jdbc(url=url, table="tablaPsd", mode="overwrite", properties=properties)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMc1b.png)

I'd appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `df.select(...)` results to a new dataframe then use the new dataframe to write using `.jdbc`

**`Example:`**

```
df = sqlContext.read.text("wasbs://container@almacen.blob.core.windows.net/TEXTPSD.DAT")
df1 = df.select(
    df.value.substr(1,12).alias('valor0'),
    df.value.substr(13,9).alias('valor1'),
    df.value.substr(22,12).alias('valor2'),
    df.value.substr(34,80).alias('nombre')
)
df2 = DataFrameWriter(df1)
df2.jdbc(url=url, table="tablaPsd", mode="overwrite", properties=properties)
```